# Can I make Contact Form 7 change over to a new page?

Tags: forms, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm trying to set up a form for people to fill in, however I want to split it up into sections so as to not create a long list of different details on just one page.

For example:

PAGE ONE Includes

- First Name:
- Last Name:
- Phone:
- Email:
- Start Date:
- Start Time:
- End Date:
- End Time:
- Address:
  (Multiple address lines)

PAGE TWO Includes

- Coverage:
- Quantity:
- Subject Information:
  Etc, etc.

I was wondering if anyone knew if it's possible to split these two steps on different pages whilst keeping the information placed for Page One, without having to send two separate emails.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Not sure how can we do it with contact form 7 but yes this can be done by gravity form. BTW plugin support questions are off-topic!

Comment: Sorry, I've seen many people post plugin questions here, one person even suggested posting here for a quicker response.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could use JavaScript or jQuery.

Put each "page" of the form in a its own section / div.  Hide all of the divs but the first, and have a button which will hide the current section/div and show the next.  On the final div you have the submit button.

This will help you out if you choose to go down this route: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar

Comment: Ahh okay, I quite like that. I'll look into it and give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: This is what I do when I need a multi-step form. +1

Comment: Same, it's the best approach IMHO, better for both UX and UI!

Answer (score 3):

In order to split a long list of form into multiple steps using Contact Form 7. There is a free plugin availble, [Contact Form 7 Multi Steps Module](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/)

Install this plugin and follow the instructions as mentioned on the plugin's description page.

Hope this helps!